# Add outline at runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to figure out how to add a Outline UI effect to a graphic at runtime. I've looked through the documentation and googled around, and can't find anything relevant. I'm quite surprised I haven't found anything.... Anyways, it's contained within the latest UI, namespace is `UnityEngine.UI.Outline`, and I can add the outline without issues using the Inspector just fine.... just can't figure out how to modify a gameobject/image and apply the outline. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How have you tried previously? Some [failed] code would be nice. In most instances, it's just a case of parentObject.AddComponent<Outline>(); (or something similar)

Comment: You could add a panel behind the UI image which is slightly bigger than the image, and just show and hide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to LokiSinclair for pointing me int he right direction... I had originally tried that method, but some logical error was throwing the code off, I was able to get it running using this method:

```
        var outline = gameObject.AddComponent<Outline>();
        outline.useGraphicAlpha = false;
        outline.effectColor = new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, .8f);
        outline.effectDistance = new Vector2(1, -1);
```